# Group rules together in compact output?

Tags: css, sass

I've just started using SCSS to generate my CSS files.  The "compact" style is my preferred output style, but I'm not sure how to group base-level rules together without nesting them.  This is basically a question about aesthetics.

In clearer terms, usually this SCSS:

```
h1 { font-size: 32px; }
h2 { font-size: 24px; }
h3 { font-size: 18px; }
```

...will compile into this CSS:

```
h1 { font-size: 32px; }

h2 { font-size: 24px; }

h3 { font-size: 18px; }
```

But I want to remove that extra line between the rules, selectively, such that it compiles instead into this CSS:

```
h1 { font-size: 32px; }
h2 { font-size: 24px; }
h3 { font-size: 18px; }
```

In general, I really LIKE that Sass puts newlines between base-level rules, but occasionally I want to selectively group rules together without nesting them.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I use sass syntax but it should work the same. When you are watching the file add the style option tag.

```
`sass --watch --style compressed your_sass_file.sass:your_stylesheet_name.css`
```

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately I don't think I was clear in my original question.  I've edited for clarity.  I currently use the compact style because that's what I (and my team) prefer.  But we sometimes want to remove those extra lines of whitespace that are produced between rules, such that we can group similar rules together.  Currently the only way we can find to do that is to nest those rules within another rule.